# jQuery replacing only one instance of .first()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have something like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel" id="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
        <!--Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>

<!--Same thing again-->

<div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel" id="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
        <!--Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I use `$(".carousel-inner div:first").addClass('active');`, the class `active` is added only the `div` of the *first* `carousel-inner`. The second one remains as it is.

Is this the expected behavior? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You have used **:first** selector so it will add active class on first div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would add it to first div only.

Do this:

```
$(".carousel-inner div:first-child").addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

`.carousel-inner div:first` selects the first occurance of `.carousel div` !
You may use jquery `find()` for this purpose:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".carousel-inner").find("div:first").addClass('active');
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel" id="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
        sdsd
    </div>
</div>

<!--Same thing again-->

<div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel" id="carousel-inner2">
    <div class="item">
        dfgdfg
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:first` CSS selector is returning the first instance of a `div` element located within a `div` with the class of `carousel-inner`. AKA, the first instance of `.carousel-inner div`

If you want the first instance of a `div` within every instance of a `.carousel-inner` element use a child selector, `:nth-child(1)` or `:first-child`